# SOClearChat -- Helpful Chat functions

Tags: script, chat, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

A Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script packing some helpful functions for Stack Overflow chat.

To install, click: <kbd>[Install SO ClearChat](https://github.com/lbotinelly/SOClearChat/raw/master/so-clearchat.user.js)</kbd>

Source: [github.com/lbotinelly/SOClearChat](https://github.com/lbotinelly/SOClearChat)

It adds four functionalities, 3 present as links under the room title:

> [image: usage]

- **clear** - clear all messages;
- **remove media** - replaces all embedded video and image resources with a text tag:

> [image: remove messages with medias]

- **Night Mode** - toggles night mode on/off;
- **Hover thumbnails** for starred images:

> [image: thumbnails for starred images]

Comment: Y U no like memes? https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPmjD.jpg

Comment: @Bacco I do like'em. *Deep fried*.